# Prevent Activity from relaunching when clicking on the notification

Tags: java, android, notifications, android-pendingintent

I'm trying to achieve the following :

1 - If I click on Notification and `MyActivity` is already launched (in foreground)

**Do nothing.**

2 - If I click on Notification and `MyActivity` is already launched (in background)

**Call it and not relaunch it.**

3 - If I click on Notification and `MyActivity` is not launched

**Launch the activity**

My code :

```
private Notification buildNotification() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
            builder = new Notification.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID);
        else
            builder = new Notification.Builder(this);
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyActivity.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP |
                Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP |
                Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT | PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE);
        builder.setContentTitle(StringUtils.getString(R.string.app_name))
                .setContentText(StringUtils.getString(R.string.app_is_running))
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher_foreground)
                .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_HIGH)
                .setOnlyAlertOnce(false)
                .setAutoCancel(false)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
        return builder.build();
    }
```

**The issue :**

The activity is always relaunching, even if the activity is already launched in foreground or background.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
android:launchMode="singleTop"
```

in your manifest